# Consequences of re-using socket in TIME_WAIT state

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, ethernet

It is a very well-known fact that the risk of using the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option is that the socket that has been in the `TIME_WAIT` state may be replaced by a new socket (can in Windows)/ port and the new socket may get stale packets designed for the old socket. But what are the **real** risks of this?

The only real danger is that the stale packet may have the exact sequence number that the new socket expects or the one within the receive window, in which case the application layer may get the wrong data from TCP/IP stack, which can severely affect the application. Is that the only case real case? If so, it is actually pretty severe enough not to rely on `SO_REUSEADDR`.

Comment: You can't reuse a socket. You can reuse a *port.* Your question doesn't make sense as stated.

Comment: @user207421 thanks for correcting that part. But what are the real risks to an actual application witch does the business logic?

Comment: @user207421 there was no real answer around - just saying it is *risky*, which is meaningless for an application developer

Comment: seriously why it has been voted down...

Comment: @user207421 "*You can't reuse a socket*" - on Windows, you can, if you use `DisconnectEx()` to close the connection while leaving the socket alive, and then use `AcceptEx()` or `ConnectEx()` to reuse the socket.

Comment: Thanks, Remy. Edited my question. But one one million dollar question. Leaving socket re-use aside.  Is there a chance of getting a corrupted data frame because if by some bad luck, the same port would start the seq num at which a stray packet is coming?